# In a shell script, how to suspend and resume FTP session without losing connection?

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

From a shell script, after creating an FTP session with another machine, how can I suspend the FTP session to perform tasks in the shell, then resume the FTP session, perhaps numerous times, without performing an FTP login each time?

Mac, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In the common *nix `ftp` command-line client (as well as the Windows `ftp.exe` command-line client), you can execute a local shell command using the `!` command:

```
# remote pwd
pwd
# local pwd
! pwd
```

The bare `!` will run a shell. After you exit the shell, you return to the `ftp`.

---

Reference: [ftp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp):

> `! [command [args]]`
>
> Invoke an interactive shell on the local machine. If there are arguments, the first is taken to be a command to execute directly, with the rest of the arguments as its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For most command shells, `^Z` will suspend the ftp session and place it, dormant, in the background.  Once you are done with your other work, you can return to your session by typing `fg`.

A full description of the `bash` job control commands, and the `fg` command, in particular, can be found in the `bash` man page in the JOB CONTROL section.

Comment: Thanks, but talking about pausing it within a script.