# Sleep in an ftp bash session

Tags: bash, ftp

I am launching an FTP session automatically, with

```
ftp -inv globe.forward.my_machine <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd petitions
ls
put my_petition.txt
sleep 10
cd ../data
get my.tar
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

It almost always works, but when it doesn't I have the suspicion that it could be due to some time lag launching the petition and receiving an answer. So, I introduced an `sleep` command to ensure the files are available, but I obtain *"?Invalid command"*. How can I force an sleep in an `ftp` session in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `sleep` command in `ftp`.

An easy solution is to execute the `sleep` in a shell. Use `!` to escape to the shell temporarily:

```
!sleep 10
```

See [`ftp` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp).

A related question: [In a shell script, how to suspend and resume FTP session without losing connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35494720/850848)